# Created a module that has a form: How do I display on a page?

Tags: 7, forms

I just created a module called member_survey that just contains a simple information gathering form.

What I'd like to do is create a page with the url www.example.com/member-survey that contains the survey that i just created.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6).

```
function member_survey_menu() {
  $items['member-survey'] = array(
    'title' => 'Your title',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('your_form_function'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Replace `your_form_function` with the function that generates the form.

Replace `array('access content')` with your desired permissions.

You can also use the [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module instead of writing a module.

Comment: Okay, but where can I view the form?

Comment: it's showing up under member_survey but not member-survey

Comment: It will be shown on _member-survey_ page.Perhaps you have a typo in `$items['member-survey']`

Comment: no there was no type, but I did have to clear the cache to make it appear. :P